Storing tokens using Cache API in a service worker
I have a project where I need to attach a bearer token onto HTTP requests going to an API. The straightforward way to persist the token is to store it in localStorage and then manually attach it to every fetch call. However, to prevent/partially mitigate XSS risks, I was wondering if the following was a better alternative:

All HTTP communication to the API is handled in a separate service worker. The "rendering process code" (i.e. the one with access to the DOM) communicates with the service worker via postMessage etc to access the api
The token is stored in a global variable in the service worker and persisted by the Cache API
To prevent the main page form accessing the Cache API, I set caches.match, caches.open etc all to null in a script element at the very very top of every page
A very strict CSP directive for workers is set so that no untrusted code can run on any worker

The cache API was chosen instead of indexeddb etc mainly because I didn't think I would need it at all so disabling it in the page process had limited side effects.
Wondering what potential flaws this solution might have.
